# Displaying map from GeoServer on mobile device

Tags: geoserver, mobile, android

I am attempting to display a map from geoserver on mobile device, for example an Android Smartphone.

I have already set my map to GeoServer via localhost, but I really don't know how to call the map with my mobile device.

My friend told me to use wifi from my computer to transfer the map to my mobile device, but I am unsure how to do this

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect your mobile device to a WiFi on the same network as your geoserver.
2. Point your mobile's browser to your geoserver's URL (http://geoserverHostNameOrIP:8080/geoserver/...)